# How to update controller variable with 'ng-model' AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to get user input through a text box using ng-model, and append to a base URL for a http.get call as follow;

index.html:

```
<html ng-app='vidRoute'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Search Video</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/custom/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/custom/responsive.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='mainwrapper'>
            <div id='header' ng-controller="searchController">
                <input type="text" id="searchTxt" ng-model="append">
                <a href="#/search" id="searchBtn">Search Video</a>
            </div>

            <div id="poster">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>       

        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/vendor/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/vendor/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/vendor/angular-mocks.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/custom/searchcontroller.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app/javascript/custom/vidRoute.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

searchcontroller.js

```
'use strict';

var vidcontrol = angular.module("vidcontrol", []);

vidcontrol.controller("vidcontroller", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/airing_today?api_key=d5e87524383e2872a9555990b268dc5b').success(function(response) {
        $scope.results = response.results;
    });
}]);

vidcontrol.controller('searchController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        var url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=d5e87524383e2872a9555990b268dc5b&query=";
        // var searchTxt = $('#searchTxt').val();// this works fine when used
        var searchUrl = url + append; //$scope.append also logs 'undefined' on the console
        $http.get(searchUrl).success(function (response) {
            $scope.searchResults = response.results;    
        });
    }]);
```

but I'm not getting any response. when I log searchUrl on console, I could see that append was not updated according to value from text box. I'm quite new to Angular and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: append's not defined anywhere in this code... I'm pretty sure you need to read it out of `$scope` with the way you have it written here.

Comment: When I use $scope.append, it gives 'undefined'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I see the issue. When controller loaded, it executes controller code. That mean REST query runs before view is built. That is reason you see undefined problem. Solution is to define a method in controller which will be invoked when you click "Search Video".

Update view

```
 <a href="#/search" id="searchBtn" ng-click="search()">Search Video</a> //Look at ng-click
```

Update Controller:

```
vidcontrol.controller('searchController', ['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http) {
            var url = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=d5e87524383e2872a9555990b268dc5b&query=";
            $scope.search = function(){ // Look at here, Defined a method to invoke on "Search Video" link click
                var searchUrl = url + $scope.append; 
                $http.get(searchUrl).success(function(response) {
                    $scope.searchResults = response.results;
                });
            };
        } ]);
```

Comment: when I use var searchUrl = url + $scope.append;, I have searchUrl = http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=d5e87524383e2872a9555990b268dc5b&query=undefined. which means that $scope.append is undefined

Comment: I just realized you posted "vidcontrol" module code and you are using "vidRoute" module (<html ng-app='vidRoute'>).. Can you please post "vidRoute" module and its controller "searchController" controller.

Comment: vidRoute is the module that handles my routing

Comment: vidRoute is the module that handles my routing  I've uploaded it [here on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stg0x1op/)

Comment: Why are you are using to separate modules for routing and controller? any special reason?

Comment: No special reason. Just trying to keep the code neat by separating my route from the controllers.

Comment: And when I use a method as suggested, I get the following error: ReferenceError: append is not defined
    at Scope.$scope.search

Comment: However, if I replace `var searchUrl = url + append;` with `var searchUrl = url + $scope.append;`, then I have it. but develop another problem. the generated `$scope.searchResults` is not accessible to the view

Comment: Look at http://codepen.io/ksree/pen/ogLOMj. I suspect you are trying access searchResults out of controller scope. Try moving div#poster into div#header tag.

Comment: But why is the div#poster not accessible to the controller, seeing that the same controller has been specified in the route? Its a bit confusing